# С#. Можно ли прервать задачу удалив объект с методом который её создал?

Tags: c#, task

Есть примерно такой простой код:

```
SomeClass _someClassObject;

public async void UpMethod()
{
    _someClassObject = new SomeClass();

    // этот метод возвращает Task<SomeResultClass>
    var task = _someClassObject.SomeMethodAsync(/*параметры*/); 

    var result = await task; // ждёмс...
    var r1 = result.r1;
    var r2 = result.r2;
}
```

Пользователь нажимает кнопочку и вызывается `UpMethod()` он долгий... и даже несколько зависящий от действий пользователя.
И тут пользователь решает отменить действия которые выполняются внутри задачи. Он нажимет на кнопочку *Отмена* и вызывается метод `Cancel()`

```
public void Cancel(){
    _someClassObject = null;// вот тут и вопрос
}
```

От этого действия задача отменится?

Comment: Ссылка на ранее созданный SomeClass по прежнему в области видимости, ведь await task не завершился, а этот task удерживает ссылку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В официальном [мануле](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation) по моему написано, что корректно отменять Task можно 2-мя путями:

1. Через return
2. CancellationToken

Если бы его можно было отменить простым присвоением, то там бы так и написали.

А вообще, как вы себе это представляете? Откуда среда должна знать, как правильно выполнить завершение задачи, если вы сами об этом не позаботитесь? Если она тупо убьет задачу, то программа может остаться в непонятном состоянии, так как она могла работать с какими-то внешними данными.